# How to create a Git pull request from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I can't seem to find in the egit documentation how to create a pull request from within Eclipse once you push a branch to a remote repository.

All the searches I've tried pull up command line answers or answers on how to do it from the web interface.

So right now I'm having to:

- Make changes and commit locally to my branch
- Do a "Team -> Push Branch..."
- Once that's complete then open the remote repository from web browser and create a pull request from my branch there.

I want to be able to do that last step from within Eclipse.

Comment: Are you trying to Push Branch everytime you make changes?

Comment: Share a screenshot. I can help you with this configuration. You can set the Fetch, Pull and Push request using EGIT plug in

Comment: There is no screen shot to share.  I'm looking for a menu command in Eclipse that is the equivalent of "Create Pull Request" that you have when using Git via a web browser.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Neither with egit nor with the github mylyn connector (which only allows you to track existing pull requests). You have to use the browser or other tools.

However, if your git server returns a result message containing a URL to your newly pushed branch, then the push result dialog shows that URL as a clickable link that you can use to open your browser more quickly on the right page to create a pull request.